# Unable to display custom ribbon button only on one form of an entity

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have created a ribbon button on the opportunity entity in CRM 2013 and have used a custom enable rule to display the button only on one form from the two available (admin, sales).

I am able to see the button on web on the right form (admin), but it doesn't seem to be visible on Outlook client. I am using the following JavaScript to enable/disable the button and for some reason it looks like the JS is always returning false when called from Outlook.

I am using SetTimeout since Outlook seems to be taking time getting the objects and throwing an error if that's not used.

Is there a better way to enable the button on one form and not the other?

```
function EnableRibbonButton()
{
    var client = Xrm.Page.context.client.getClient();
    if(client == "Web")
    {
        var form = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector;
        if(form != null)
        {
            var formItem = form.getCurrentItem();
            if(formItem != null)
            {
                var formId = formItem.getId();
                if(formId == "ADMINFORMGUID")
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if(client == "Outlook")
    {
        var form = getForms();
        var formItem = getFormItem(form);
        var formId = getFormID(formItem);
        if(formId == "ADMINFORMGUID")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function getForms()
{
    var form = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector;
    if(form != null)
    {
        return form;
    }
    else
    {
        window.setTimeout("getForms()", 100);
    }
}

function getFormItem(form)
{
    var formItem = form.getCurrentItem();
    if(formItem != null)
    {
        return formItem;
    }
    else
    {
        window.setTimeout("getFormItem("+form+")", 100);
    }
}
function getFormID(formItem)
{
    var formId = formItem.getId();
    if(formId != null)
    {
        return formId;
    }
    else
    {
        window.setTimeout("getFormID("+formItem+")", 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, microsoft is well aware of this issue in outlook. For your case i think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) immediately returns (the timeoutID) and will execute the first argument at a later time, so you'll need some kind of callback mechanism to continue to the next step.

Furthermore, giving `setTimeout` a string as first argument is a form of "implicit eval", which generally is undesirable.

Example of `getForm` with callback:

```js
function getFormSelector(callback) {
    var formSelector = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector;

    if(typeof callback === 'function') {

        if(!formSelector) {
            window.setTimeout(
                // Create closure for callback function.
                function() {
                    getFormSelector(callback);
                },
                100 // milliseconds
            );
            return;
        }

        callback(formSelector);
        return;
    }

    return formSelector;
}
```